# Dynamic edittext not showing up text in an Android app

Tags: android, android-edittext

Creating a dynamic `EditText` as follows

```
EditText myText = new EditText(this);
myText.setId(ctrlKey);
myText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_edittext);
myText.setClickable(true);
myText.setCursorVisible(true);

myText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
myText.setTextSize(12);
myText.setText("may i");    //pageField.getValue());
myText.setSelection(0);
myText.setCursorVisible(true);

if (pageField.getMultiline()) {
myText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
}
else
 myText.setSingleLine(true);
//myText.setEnabled(false);
pageLayout.setLayoutParams(ctrllp);
pageLayout.addView(myText, ctrllp);
```

`Edittext` is created and visible at appropriate location, but I can't see the text in the `Edittext`, and when I try a place cursor in it, it seems like there is already text in the `Edittext` (the cursor position and help words shown below confirms). Even if I type something in the `Edittext` also not visible.

XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.topazsystems.pdoc.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">        
   <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<com.topazsystems.pdoc.ZoomableViewGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity = "center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/zoomLayout"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:id="@+id/RelLayout">
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</RelativeLayout>
</com.topazsystems.pdoc.ZoomableViewGroup>
<include layout="@layout/fragment_navigation"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In activity oncreate I am calling a method which contains the control rendering code.

```
  pageLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(com.topazsystems.pdoc.R.id.RelLayout);
 //to display page controls during appload
    pageControlsList = pdfRenderer.GetPageControls();
    if (pageControlsList != null) {
        if (pageControlsList.size() > 0) {
            generateControls();
            //fillDefaultDocControls();
            mfrg.showPage(pdfRenderer.getmCurrentPageNum(), true, this);
        }
    }
```

where generatecontrols() contains the edittext creation code and mfrg is instance of fragment.

Comment: remove myText.setText("may i"); and instead use myText.setHint("may i");

Comment: I'm considering text "may i" as hint , if not pls let me know

Comment: I want to display some text in the edittext widget, its not hint.. I tried setting both text and hint..not working..

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: what happens if you remove `setSelection(0)`?

Comment: no use.. the same result

Answer (score 0):

Check once removing background resource if it is the culprit. so remove the following line and check if text is visible.

```
 myText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_edittext);
```

Comment: i already checked it.. even after removing that line also.. text is not visible

Answer (score 0):

You have passed wrong context in `EditText` , you need to pass context of parent of `EditText` like below code.

in your code you are added `EditText` into `pageLayout`.

```
EditText myText = new EditText(pageLayout.getContext());
```

Comment: Even after editing the context also.. the same.. I can't see the text

Comment: Try to add view in parent without adding params.

Comment: If i remove the parameters and add the widget, i can see the text but the control is placed in the top left corner of the layout, even though I set the left and top of the control..

Comment: add your activity and xml in query.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me.  After a detailed study I observed that the text area seems to be very small and the text is not visible. Simply adding the following line solved the issue.

```
 myText.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```